# How to check a module has been activated or not in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

How to check if a org-timer module has been activated or not.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>C-c C-x C-j</kbd>

should actually work. It is the default chord bound to the command  <kbd>M-x org-clock-jump-to-current-clock</kbd>  .

Check your .emacs if you have changed the keybindings. If <kbd>C-c C-x C-j</kbd> is unbound and it still does not work you can try and put this in your .emacs:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-x C-j") 'org-clock-jump-to-current-clock)
```

Comment: I figured out that this works only when in org buffer. But is this related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>C-c C-x C-j</kbd>

See <kbd>C-h k C-c C-x C-j</kbd> for docs.

Comment: "C-c C-x j is undefined" is the message displayed

Comment: Talespin_Kit: Was that a typo, or are you saying that `C-j` is coming through as a plain `j` ?

Comment: @Talespin_Kit When I used C-c C-x C-j my status bar provides the message: org-clock-goto: No active or recent clock task. I don't have any added bindings for clocking tasks so it should be working. Or do you mean something other than clocks when you say org-timer

Comment: I find out that C-c C-x C-j works only in org buffer. But how is this related to the question.